# Displaying multiple rows from database to WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, richtextbox

I'm making a WPF app and I want to display every single row on the table below from my database

[image: Ingredients Table]

on the format like: Amount + Ingredient:

For example:

- 3 garlic cloves, thinly sliced.
- 6 (4-ounce) skinless chicken thighs.
- 1 tablespoon fish sauce

and so on.

But I'm confused about what WPF components I should use. I'm thinking of using RICHTEXTBOX or ListBox but I'm not sure how to have each record displayed one by one. Any help? I'm so new .Net programmer so sorry if my question bugs you!

Comment: Have you looked at `DataGrid` ?

Comment: Almost every ItemsControl is able to display the record in WPF, all what differs is the presentation. in some cases you have to build your own eg ItemsControl, ListBox where as some have pre-built features eg ListView, DataGrid

Comment: I just figured out that I should concatenate content of the two column into 1 column and display it to the app. Life would be much easier:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your database data loaded into a collection in a viewmodel...

Bind the collection to a data grid control. It's quick and easy and looks like what you want.

If you want a bit more design control, I'd personally bind to an ItemsControl and create an itemtemplate to display your data.

Your question is valid and not annoying, however being Microsoft, there are as many different ways to achieve this as there are WPF developers.